# jQuery function steps off into the jQuery source code after execution completes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI to enhance two ASP.Net radios. On click I want to alter the UI, and when I step through with the Chrome debugger, it works as expected, until the end of the function when it exits, where the debugger then steps into the actual jquery source, and the changes that my code made get reverted. What is going on?

The function is below:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var uploadBox = $this.parent().parent().next();
            var manualBox = $this.parent().parent().next().next();
            if ($this.attr('id') == "<%= UploadRadioButton.ClientID %>"){
                manualBox.hide();
                uploadBox.show();
            }
            else{
                uploadBox.hide();
                manualBox.show();
            }
        }
     );
```

(.toggle() doesn't work for some reason)

The debugger enters into this snippet of the jQuery source:

```
if ( ret !== undefined ) {
    event.result = ret;
    if ( ret === false ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    }
 }
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the javascript is sitting in a UserControl.

Comment: comment e.preventDefault(); with // and try again?

Comment: I recommend against using a server side language to generate JavaScript. Rather, use classes and `[data-*]` attributes along with jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method.

Comment: @zzzzBov I had actually tried that first, but for some reason the attributes got stripped off- very weird!

Answer (score 1):

When it finishes your event handler, it steps into the jQuery code that manages event handlers (the code that actually called your event handler) and what you posted there is the jQuery code than processes the return value from your event handler to decide whether you intend to stop propagation and prevent default behavior.  This is perfectly normal.

Comment: That makes sense, but why are my changes being afterwards?

Comment: @lee - we'd have to see your actual page to comment on what else is going on here.

Comment: @lee - I don't see anything obvious there.  I'd have to be able to run something where you could reproduce the problem to do more.